# Jquery Lookup autocomplete

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I have a csv file with a list of postcodes and a list of there corresponding areas so
for example

```
AA1 1BV, Main area
AA1 1BX, Main area
AA1 1BZ, Suburban Area
```

and so on.

There are 3000 lines in the csv file so making a select box with all the selections would be a bit of a pain.
Also I need to be able to do this via a csv file rather than putting it into a database

The problem is we need the full postcode to get the area, but we are not allowed to accept the full post code as an answer in the form. 
So what im after is when they type there postcode into the text box it will either change it into the area. or display the area somewhere so they can add it to another textbox.

I was thinking that JQuery autocomplete may be the answer.. but its not really autocomplete more auto change.

Any ideas on what I should be looking for?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can use for example a javascript array rather than csv you can do this quite easily with something like:

```
var pcArray = [];
pcArray['AA1 1BZ'] = "Main area";
pcArray['AA1 1BX'] = "Main area";
pcArray['AA1 1BZ'] = "Suburban Area";
```

...

Then lets say you have two textboxes, once for postcodes and one for areas:

```
<input type="text" id="pc" name="pc" /><input type="text" id="area" name="area" />
```

you could do something like this with jQuery:

```
$("#pc").on("change", function(){
    if(pcArray[$(this).val()] !== undefined) {
        $("#area").val(pcArray[$(this).val()]);
    }
});
```